# Layout with header, footer and content section in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently developing a single page application consisting of a header, footer and content section. The content section should always fill the available space between header and footer and in case the view port is too small the user should be able to scroll the whole page. That means the footer is not sticky in that way.

Putting all three parts inside a flexbox and setting `flex: auto 1 1` to the content does not take any effect since IE11 has issues with flex-elements whose container have 100% as minimum height.

Do you know any technique making this kind of layout possible?

**Update:**

To illustrate the problem, I provide a snippet.

**Update 2:**

Since I want to fade in the view (class `.view`) element into the previous one depending on the current route I have to use `position: relative` on the content element. Unfortunately `flex-shrink: 0` does not take an effect anymore.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000000;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica;
  }

  #app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  .header-section {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .footer-secton {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    flex: auto 1 1;
    background: rgba(64, 124, 214, 0.5);
  }

  .view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id ="app" class="container">
    <header class="header-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="view">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
         dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
         dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
         eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
         eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you paste the overal code?

Comment: I've provided a snipprt to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Use jQuery to set the content and the header minimum height to cover the browser. Then it will automatically go to the remaining space.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `min-height: 100%`, I would use `height: 100%` and `overflow: visible` for that wrapper element. That avoids the min-height problem and will expand (and scroll) if necessary due to content.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If I decrease the height of the browser window, the footer is placed above the content at the bottom of the view port.

Comment: try to add `overflow: visible` and/or `flex-shrink: 0` to the content element

Comment: `flex-shrink: 0` looks promising.

Comment: If I want to extend my example to provide nice fade-effects i need to set `position: relative;` for `.content`. Inserting an absolute positioned child into this element destroys the positive effect of `flex-shrink: 0;`. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I've updated my snippet and added a further description to my initial post. If you want to have more detailed information let me know.

Comment: please note the second answer including snippet I added.

Answer (score 3):

IE11 has [poor support](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) for flexbox. You can use this old-school solution as fallback...

**Sticky footer**

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%; background: blue;}
#header, #footer {position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0;}
#header {top: 0; background: red;}
#footer {bottom: 0; background: green;}
#content {padding: 100px 0;}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**Non-sticky footer**

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%; background: blue;}
#header, #footer {width: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 2;}
#header {position: fixed; top: 0; background: red;}
#footer {position: absolute; bottom: 0; background: green;}
#page {min-height: 100%; position: relative;}
#content {padding: 100px 0;}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="page">
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful as well. Thanks. But I still prefer taking advantage of flexbox-based layouts.

Comment: You are welcome. Flexbox is modern, but browser incompatibilities are not really an advantage. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Set min height using jQuery based on the browser viewport.
This will you to fit the content inside the viewport.
This will support in all the browser regardless of the content.

min-height is used to identify the content occupied spaces. If the content is more than that we expecting, then the scrollbar will automatically come. Otherwise, the content will occupy the viewport.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).resize(function() {
setContentHeight();

});

function setContentHeight(){
 var contentHeight = window.innerHeight - $('.footer-section').height()-19;
$('.page-wrapper').css('min-height', contentHeight+'px');
}

setContentHeight();
});
```

```css
.container{
background-color:yellow;

}

.page-wrapper{
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
}

.header-section{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}

.footer-section{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id ="app" class="container">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
    <header class="header-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut       labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
      dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
      invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
      justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet.
    </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: That would be an option as well, but I prefer a solution based on css only to improve UI performance. Given the fact that this is a vue.js application I'd consider the DOM-API wrapped inside a vue.js directive.

Comment: This won't give a bad approach as well. This is what most of the css templates are acheiving. Write your own custom directive and put this code and apply it where you need it. That will take care of your problem and will not provide you the bad performance. Custom directive: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html. Article to follow: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199114/How-to-Create-Admin-Responsive-Template-using-Boot

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to the changed code of the answer, using an absolutely positioned element.

In this case, it's sufficient to add `overflow: auto` to the absolutely positioned `.view` element to allow it to scroll inside its parent, as demonstrated in this snippet (I added some more content to make the scrollbar visible):

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000000;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica;
  }

  #app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  .header-section {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .footer-secton {
    flex-shrink: 0;
 }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    flex: auto 1 1;
    background: rgba(64, 124, 214, 0.5);

  }

  .view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id ="app" class="container">
    <header class="header-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="view">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
         dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
         dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
         eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
         eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
         dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
         dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
         eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
         eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
         dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
         dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
         eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
         eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
         dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
         dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
         eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
         eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer-section">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I need a custom scrollbar for this purpose but ironically IE11 is not able to scroll the content inside `.view`. Sometimes this browser is a challenge.

Answer (score -2):

No need to fix this issue manually, as you can use latest bootstrap & it will solve it in IE 11.

You can see here https://www.bootply.com/QIdjUoiMOq

Comment: Since to some constraints I have to avoid dependencies to other layout-frameworks. So boostrapt is not an option for my special use case.